# Passing value into server object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

recently i am working on a project and i am stucked with a problem. if you help me to solve that issue, you make me really happy.

the problem is, in my .aspx page i have a code block in `<% %>` and i am producing some new attributes to use in the page. When i try to pass a value to a server object via new generated attribute, i am not able to use `<%=exampleAttribute%>` or `<%#exampleAttribute%>` structure to set the value.

such as

a server button object, i want to set a value to CommandArgument via `<%=exampleAttribute%>` but i am not able to do.

or

again for a server button object, i want to set a value for a javascript function in the clientClick event.

What is the thing that i am doing wrong?? Could you please help me on this to solve that problem. I will be waiting for any answer. Thanks in advance and i wish you all the best.

Edit:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="test" OnCommand="test_Command" CommandArgument='testData' />
```

if i set the data manually, i can read the commandArgument but if i use method like one of below

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnCommand="Button1_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("gelgel") %>' />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" OnCommand="Button2_Click" CommandArgument='<%#gelgel %>' />
```

Thats the code i use and yes gelgel is a public argument. when i try to read commandargument, i get empty value.

Comment: what message are you getting

Comment: also is exampleattribute a public variable for the page???

Comment: PLease show some code,

Comment: give me couple mins please and i will add some code pics

Comment: `<%#Eval("gelgel")%>` works in databound context such as repeater, gridview and so on provided you have a field / property named gelgel. `<%#gelgel%>` works if you have public / protected gelgel property. Look as well at `OnCommand="Button2_Click"`. I suspect you initially had `OnClick=...` and then change to `OnCommand`. The two handlers have different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the property, `gelgel`, then perhaps you can consider doing it in the code behind.

```
Button1.CommandArgument = gelgel;
```

Comment: button is a server object that copying itself in a loop but the method for every button is same and i am trying to catch the id of the selected section while clicking the button. therefore, this approach is not helping but yet thanks.